# Errors using curve_fit for Guassian fit of data

Tags: python, scipy, data-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to do a guassian fit for some experimental data but I keep running into error after error. I've followed a few different threads online but either the fit isn't good (it's just a horizontal line) or the code just won't run. I'm following [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826859/gaussian-fit-in-python) from another thread. Below is my code.

I apologize if my code seems a bit messy. There are some bits from other attempts when I tried making it work. Hence the "astropy" import.

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt
import pandas as pd
import statistics as stats
from astropy import modeling


def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma, offset):
    return a*m.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2)) + offset

# Python program to get average of a list
def Average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

wavelengths = [391.719, 391.984, 392.248, 392.512, 392.777, 393.041, 393.306, 393.57, 393.835, 394.099, 391.719, 391.455, 391.19, 390.926, 390.661, 390.396]
intensities = [511.85, 1105.85, 1631.85, 1119.85, 213.85, 36.85, 10.85, 6.85, 13.85, 7.85, 511.85, 200.85, 80.85, 53.85, 14.85, 24.85]



n=sum(intensities)
mean = sum(wavelengths*intensities)/n
sigma = m.sqrt(sum(intensities*(wavelengths-mean)**2)/n)


def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*m.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = opt.curve_fit(gaus,wavelengths,intensities,p0=[1,mean,sigma])
print(popt)


plt.scatter(wavelengths, intensities)

plt.title("Helium Spectral Line Peak 1")
plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
plt.ylabel("Intensity (a.u.)")

plt.show()
```

Thanks to the kind user, my curve seems to be working more reasonably well. However, one of the points seems to be back connecting to an earlier point? Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you do a little clean up in your code.  There are a bunch of irrelevant imports, and the function `gaus` is defined twice, with different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first is that you are performing vector operation on `list` which gives you the first error in the line `mean = sum(wavelengths*intensities)/n`. Therefore, you should use `np.array` instead. The second is that you take `math.exp` on python `list` which again throws an error as it takes a real number, so you should use `np.exp` here instead.

The following code solves your problem:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt

wavelengths = [391.719, 391.984, 392.248, 392.512, 392.777, 393.041,
               393.306, 393.57, 393.835, 394.099, 391.719, 391.455,
               391.19, 390.926, 390.661, 390.396]
intensities = [511.85, 1105.85, 1631.85, 1119.85, 213.85, 36.85, 10.85, 6.85,
               13.85, 7.85, 511.85, 200.85, 80.85, 53.85, 14.85, 24.85]

wavelengths_new = np.array(wavelengths)
intensities_new = np.array(intensities)

n=sum(intensities)
mean = sum(wavelengths_new*intensities_new)/n
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(intensities_new*(wavelengths_new-mean)**2)/n)

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = opt.curve_fit(gaus,wavelengths_new,intensities_new,p0=[1,mean,sigma])
print(popt)

plt.scatter(wavelengths_new, intensities_new, label="data")
plt.plot(wavelengths_new, gaus(wavelengths_new, *popt), label="fit")
plt.title("Helium Spectral Line Peak 1")
plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
plt.ylabel("Intensity (a.u.)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! How do I smooth the fit though? I looked up some things that says to use np.arrange(value) in place of the x values for the curve fit but that doesn't seem to work for me. Also seems to be an issue where the last point seems to be connecting to back somewhere in the middle. I'll edit in a screenshot to the post, but smoothing the curve may end up fixing that anyway.

Comment: For smoothing the curve, you need more and more data points in between your existing data points. Also, if my answer solved your problem, you should probably see [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :).

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to mark your answer as solved! I feel like there should be a way to smooth the curve though, because I've plotted and fitted the same thing in excel. I can smooth the curve in excel, even though I'm working with the same number of data points.

Comment: Try `np.linspace()` and use the generated data points on the x-axis and use the same for solving `gaus` function.

Comment: That worked! You're the best! :)